# SQL query to return nil for dates not present in the table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, gaps-and-islands

I have a table 'my_table'. It has the following data :

```
ID  ---   Date         

1   ---   01/30/2012  
2   ---   01/30/2012   
3   ---   05/30/2012
```

I can write a SQL query to return the count of ID's between certain dates, grouped by month, like this :

```
{"01/30/2012" => 2, "05/30/2012" => 1}
```

How can I get a result which has all the missing months between the requested dates with value '0', like this :

```
{"01/30/2012" => 2, "02/30/2012" => 0, "03/30/2012" => 0, "04/30/2012" => 0, "05/30/2012" => 1}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any calendar table available by any chance? if not, i suggest creating one for this and join it to your table - what RDBM (Oracle/MySQL/SQL Server/DB2/... + version) do you use?

Comment: I am  using PostgreSQL. Will try creatng a calendar table. Thanks.

Comment: if you need `02/30/2012` make it a varchar type instead of date ;) BTW why not use months (integers like 201201) instead of non-existent dates??

Comment: +1 Thanks deathApril, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is to have a static table with list of all the dates. In your case that's 30th of each month (what about February?). Lets call this table REF_DATE. It has a single column DT that holds the date.

Assuming that my_table only contains 0 or at most 1 distinct date (30th) in each month, what you need to do is:

```
select DT,count(ID) from 
REF_DT REF 
left outer join my_table MT 
on REF.DT=my_table.DATE
group by REF.DT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with somewhat hackish way through rails

```
class Month<Date   # for getting months in range
  def succ
    self >> 1
  end
end

range = Month.new(2010,1,1)..Month.new(2013,1,1) # range of date to query
months=Hash.new
(range).each do |month|
  months.merge!({month.to_s => 0}) # get all months as per range requirement of project
end

db_months = MyTable.find_all_by_date(range).group_by{ |u| u.date.beginning_of_month }.map{|m,v| [m.to_s , v.size]} #get all records grouped by months

all_months = months.merge(Hash[db_months]) # merge all missing months
```

Replace the range with the dates you want also the format of the date as per your requirement.

---