# Rails Migration to Generate a Calendar Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-migrations

How can I write a Ruby on Rails migration to generate a calendar table, with all the dates between Jan 2010 and Dec 2099 ?

Comment: (1) What have you tried? (2) Are you sure you need a calendar table? Some databases (such as PostgreSQL) have better ways.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. What would be a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

Comment: If I understand well, the problem with `generate_series` is that it needs to be generated for each successive query, and depending on how long the series is, it can take several milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are upto but if you want to populate the table with the dates from  Jan 2010 to Dec 2099 with migration,

You can with some thing like

```
class CreateCalendar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  (Date.new(2010,1,1)..Date.new(2099,12,31)).each do |date|
    Calender.create(:date=> date )
  end
end
```

Comment: My main issue is this : [ http://stackoverflow.com/q/11318792/1048331 ], and I'm trying to resolve it by having a calendar table.

Comment: I will wait a little before accepting your answer, in case you have a better way to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Myxtic, I have tried to resolve your original question check if that suits you. also let me know your views on it.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution to my original problem yet, but your answer to my question here definitely worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For my own reference when I find this question again.

Schema:

```
create_table :calendar_days, primary_key: :day, id: :date do |t|
  t.integer :year, null: false
  t.integer :month, null: false
  t.integer :day_of_month, null: false
  t.integer :day_of_week, null: false
  t.integer :quarter, null: false
  t.boolean :business_day, null: false
  t.boolean :week_day, null: false
end

class CalendarDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :day
end
```

Data:

```
# Non-exhaustive, needs to be customized for your needs.
def business_day?(d)
  matches = ->(month, day) { [month, day] == [d.month, d.day] }
  falls_on = ->(month, wday, r) {
    [month, wday] == [d.month, d.wday] && r.cover?(d.day)
  }

  return false if [0,6].include?(d.wday) # Weekends
  return false if matches[1, 1]   # New Years
  return false if matches[7, 4]   # Independence Day
  return false if matches[12, 25] # Christmas
  return false if matches[11, 11] # Veterans Day
  return false if falls_on[1,  1, 15..21] # MLK Day
  return false if falls_on[5,  1, 25..31] # Memorial Day
  return false if falls_on[9,  1, 1..7]   # Labor Day
  return false if falls_on[11, 4, 22..28] # Thanksgiving
  true
end

task populate_calendar_days: :environment do
  (Date.new(2013,1,1)...Date.new(2014,1,1)).each do |d|
    CalendarDay.create!(
      day:          d,
      year:         d.year,
      month:        d.month,
      day_of_month: d.day,
      day_of_week:  d.wday,
      quarter:      (d.month / 4) + 1,
      week_day:     ![0,6].include?(d.wday),
      business_day: business_day?(d)
    )
  end
end
```